# Modify the sql query in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am using sql server 2005. In this query i want the log-in user detail should also display but it is not displaying .
So please modify the query so that log-in user detail should also display with the help of session[userId].tostring();

Query written by me is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MUDMEMBER.PK_ID, MUDMEMBER.EMPLOYEE_ID, LKB.BANK_NAME, MUHD.SALARY_ACCOUNT_NO, MUHD.PF_NO,
 MUHD.PAN_NO, MUHD.GENDER, LKD.DESIGNATION_NAME FROM M_LEADERLED MLL INNER JOIN M_USER_DETAILS MUDMEMBER ON 
 MLL.LED_ID = MUDMEMBER.PK_ID AND MLL.START_DATE <= Getdate() AND MLL.END_DATE > Getdate()  AND MLL.LEADER_ID = '1' LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   M_USER_HR_DETAILS MUHD ON MUHD.FK_USER_ID = MUDMEMBER.PK_ID AND MUHD.IS_ACTIVE =1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LK_BANKS LKB ON LKB.PK_ID = MUHD.FK_BANK_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_DESIGNATION LKD ON
     LKD.DESIGNATION_VALUE = MUHD.FK_DESIGNATION_VALUE AND LKD.FK_ORGANIZATION_ID = 1 AND LKD.IS_ACTIVE = 1 WHERE MUDMEMBER.ACTIVE = 1
```

Comment: Can you give more details? like what columns do you want to display and where do you want to use session[userid]?

Comment: @Shalni: where are you writing this query, in ASP.net page or in Storeprocedure

Comment: The column i want to displaying is given above .I only want to add one more row of log-in user with same above column . Like: PK_ID=session[userid].Tostring()

Comment: @ Vijjendra : in asp.net page

Comment: God help us if this is actually being used in any kind of banking software...If you want an answer, you have to ask a more detailed question. People aren't going to keep guessing what you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net Page you can fetch the loggedin user's detail as follows:

SELECT DISTINCT MUDMEMBER.PK_ID, MUDMEMBER.EMPLOYEE_ID, LKB.BANK_NAME, MUHD.SALARY_ACCOUNT_NO, MUHD.PF_NO,
 MUHD.PAN_NO, MUHD.GENDER, LKD.DESIGNATION_NAME FROM M_LEADERLED MLL INNER JOIN M_USER_DETAILS MUDMEMBER ON 
 MLL.LED_ID = MUDMEMBER.PK_ID AND MLL.START_DATE <= Getdate() AND MLL.END_DATE > Getdate()
 AND MLL.LEADER_ID = '1' LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   M_USER_HR_DETAILS MUHD ON MUHD.FK_USER_ID = MUDMEMBER.PK_ID AND MUHD.IS_ACTIVE =1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
    LK_BANKS LKB ON LKB.PK_ID = MUHD.FK_BANK_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN LK_DESIGNATION LKD ON
     LKD.DESIGNATION_VALUE = MUHD.FK_DESIGNATION_VALUE AND LKD.FK_ORGANIZATION_ID = 1 
     AND LKD.IS_ACTIVE = 1 
     WHERE MUDMEMBER.ACTIVE = 1 AND MUDMEMBER.PK_ID ="+Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"])+"

Comment: Sorry sir, It only display one row of log-in  user id ,rest of the row will not displayed.

Comment: @Shalini:can you explain in detail what you exactly want